# Align lattice and tmap outputs using viewports

Tags: r, r-grid, tmap

I am trying to align several panels (2 maps) and a lattice output from the package openair, with some explanatory text using grid:

[image]

However, I would like the left margin of the lattice output to be aligned with the left edge of the map on the top left, and the text aligned to the left margin of the topright map.

ideally, I would like to get this:

[image]

The code I am using is this:

```
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(openair)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)


london_map <- qtm(read_osm("London"))
london_terrain <- qtm(read_osm("London", type = "stamen-terrain"))

pp_plot <- polarPlot(mydata, type="season")
top.vp <- 
  viewport(layout=grid.layout(3, 11,
                              heights=unit(c(0.5, 3.5 ,4), "inches"),
                              widths=unit(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), "inches")))


png(filename = "test.png", width = 11, height = 8, units ="in", res=72)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(top.vp)
print(london_map, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col=1:5, just="left"))
print(london_terrain, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col=6:11, just="left"))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col=1:7))
plot(pp_plot$plot, newpage=FALSE)
popViewport()     
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col=8))
grid.text("Notes: \n1. quo durius te exerces, eo facilius certabis\n2. Ursis fidimus\n3. audaces fortuna juvat \n", just=0)

dev.off()
```

I have tired working with the just arguments, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried grid.arrange() or gtable?

Something along these lines:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html

Comment: For positioning the polar plot, have a look at the `position` argument to `?print.trellis` (which documents the function that gets dispatched by your call to `plot(pp_plot,...)`). Then, for plotting the text, don't you want to place it in `layout.pos.col=6` (not `layout.pos.col=8`)? Finally, and not that it makes a difference here, your layout has 11 columns but you only supply 10 widths.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien good catch on the widths - fixed that. The position argument lets me shrink the size of the polarPlots (e.g. `position =c(0,0,0.5,0.5)` shrinks it by half, but does not fix the alignment. The text - even with the `layout.pos.col=6` is also not aligned. Maybe there is some white space that I need to trim somehow from the maps and/or the polarPlots?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien well even though the documentation says the limits are `0-1` it looks like I can get it lined up with `position = c(-0.18,0,0.82,1)`  Thank you sir!

Comment: ... and using the x=argument in `grid.text` got things lined up.  @SCDCE I will look at `gtable` and `grid.arrange` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK based on the above, this achieved what I needed. I needed to use negative positions:

```
png(filename = "test.png", width = 11, height = 8, units ="in", res=72)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(top.vp)
print(london_map, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col=1:5, just=c("left","top")))
print(london_terrain, vp = viewport(layout.pos.row = 2, layout.pos.col=6:11, just="left"))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col=1:7))
plot(pp_plot$plot, newpage=FALSE, position=c(-0.18,0,0.82,1))
popViewport()     
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 3, layout.pos.col=6))
grid.text("Notes: \n1. quo durius te exerces, eo facilius certabis\n2. Ursis fidimus\n3. audaces fortuna juvat \n", 
          x = 0.85, just = "left")

dev.off()
```